# How to redirect to Not Found page if an invalid URL is passed on Active Admin?

Tags: ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, admin, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin gem in my Rails application. I have an Item resource in the ActiveAdmin. I have allowed all the actions except new.

```
actions :all, except: [:new]
```

But in the URL if explicitly passed /admin/items/new, it throwing an ActiveRecord::Not Found error as it taking new as an id. In the description of the error, it is showing "Couldn't find Item with 'id'=new. I want to redirect to 404 or Not found page if an invalid url is passed. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks is advance!

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `ruby-on-rails-3`, `ruby-on-rails-4` and `ruby-on-rails-5`? It probably doesn't make a difference to the answer in this case, but which version are you actually using? Avoid adding irrelevant/misleading tags.

Comment: Yea, shouldn't have done that. I'm using ruby-on-rails-4.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is open up the BaseController from active admin like this. You can put it in an initializer like: `config/initializer/active_admin_overrides.rb`

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class BaseController
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :resource_not_found
    def resource_not_found
      render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```rb
def render_404
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render file: Rails.root.join('public', '404'), layout: false, status: 404 }
      format.json { render json: {}, status: 404 }
    end
  end
```

you can return like this too on any method you want to return 404 status.

```rb
render file: Rails.root.join('public', '404'), layout: false, status: 404
```